# Windows 10 VPN (Server) refusing traffic due to firewall

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, firewall

I've recently set up a VPN to one of my windows 10 machines so I could do stuff with it over the internets. Now, I used the built-in windows VPN options for this (Incoming Connection + Win 10 VPN Client).

This works, but only when the firewall on the remote system is completely disabled. Otherwise, there is no traffic because it considers the VPN a public network.

I have opened the PPTP ports (1723 + 47GRE), and I can connect to the VPN even when the Firewall is on. But when it is on, I can't actually interact with the server (even pinging times out).

I can ping/RDP and what not if the firewall is off.

Anyone have any idea on how to solve this without disabling my firewall completely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it by creating a rule allowing all traffic from my local 192.168.1.0/24 net (which includes the VPN range). It works now, however I still think this isn't used as intended.